# HTML/CSS: Two columns. Need div in right column to always be at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a blog layout that needs a "Read More" text link to always be at the bottom of the right column. It's a two column layout usually with a featured image on the left and Title, excerpt, etc on the right.  I tried using absolute positioning with extra wrappers to extend the columns to equal height and place the button, but that seems to take the button out of the flow and cause long excerpts to overlap the button.  Here is the sample code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left" style="width:40%;background:yellow;display:inline-block;">
    <h1>Lorem Lorem Lorem</h1>
    <h2>Ipsum ipsum ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem </p>
</div>
<div class="right" style="width:30%;background:gray;display:inline-block;">
    <p>This text will vary in length.  Might be longer than left column, might be shorter.</p>
    <div class="right-bottom" style="border:1px solid black;margin:3px;">Must be at bottom of right column.</div>
</div>
```

Need that .right-bottom div to always be at the bottom of the right column (and the columns to be equal height, which I think I can achieve.

Comment: Note that you miss a `:` in the "margin: 3px;" `style` of the `div` with "right-bottom" `class`:

Comment: Good point. I was wondering why i didn't get the margin in my browser, but then forgot to go back and check. thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmubfhsm/) you have a jsFiddle working. What I did is give `display: flex;` to `.container` to have the two columns with the same height. Then I give `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to `.right-bottom` to set at the bottom of the parent. Remember give to `.right` a `position: relative;` to have `.right-bottom` relative to it.

Comment: That works exactly as I need it too.  I thought when I did this before, the right column content was overrunning my absolutely placed bottom div.  Thanks!

Comment: @turkeyhundt is this https://jsfiddle.net/bmubfhsm/1/ the desired behaviour you wanted when the right hand content is quite long?

Comment: I think so.  If I just give the right column a little more bottom padding, I think I am set.

Comment: You're welcome @turkeyhundt! I recommend you to take a look to `flex-box`, it's awesome! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've moved your right column within left (might be worth renaming them now) and positioned the right column absolutely relative to the left one. I also changed the width of right from 30% to 75% (75% of 40% is 30% of the parent).

```css
.left {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left" style="width:40%;background:yellow;display:inline-block;">
    <h1>Lorem Lorem Lorem</h1>
    <h2>Ipsum ipsum ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem </p>

    <div class="right" style="width:75%; background:gray;display:inline-block;">
      <p>This text will vary in length. Might be longer than left column, might be shorter.</p>
      <div class="right-bottom" style="border:1px solid black;margin 3px;">Must be at bottom of right column.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```